# Equally space divs — anchoring them to background image — regardless of window size?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a 1387px wide contact bar (.png) and four identical divs containing contact information (email, twr, fb) that overlays it. This is what it should look like:

[image: Footer]

**Question:** 
How do I equally space the contact divs and anchor them to the background image regardless of window size?

**Structure:**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="contact-row">
        <div class="contact">
            <a class="email" href="mailto:#">email</a>  
            <a class="tw" href="http://twitter.com/#" target="_blank"></a> 
            <a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/#" target="_blank"></a>            
        </div>
        ...+ 3 more divs with class of "contact"
    </div>
</div>
```

**Styles:**

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 178px;
    background: url('../img/contact-bg.png') no-repeat center; 
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

#contact-row {  
   width: 100%;  
   height: 178px;
   border: solid 1px #aaa;  
   text-align: center;  
   overflow: hidden;  
   margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}  

.contact {  
    width: 150px;  
    height: 25px;  
    border: solid 1px #ccc;  
    display: inline-block;  
    margin: 0 50px;
}
```

I have tried many different solutions, but none stay tied to the background image or adapt to a smaller browser window. Working copy can be found here: [aaargb!!!](http://pikku.co/test/aaargb/index.html)

I'd appreciate some fresh eyes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that `#footer` *and* `#contact-row` was set to `width:100%`. Taking the relative 100% width off *both* stopped it from resizing relative to parent widths.

Turns out, `#contact-row` is unnecessary. Got rid of it and went with:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="contact">
         <a class="email" href="mailto:#">email</a>  
         <a class="tw" href="http://twitter.com/#" target="_blank"></a> 
         <a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/#" target="_blank"></a>            
    </div>
        ...+ 3 more divs with class of "contact"
</div>
```

And these styles centered `.contact` divs equally:

```
#footer {
    width:1400px;
    height:178px;
    background:url('../img/contact-bg.png') no-repeat center;
    margin:0 auto; 
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.contact {  
    width:225px;  
    height:25px;    
    display:inline-block;  
    margin:0 50px 0 68px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is you have #contact-row set to `width: 100%`. You should set it to `width: 1387px` since that's how wide it will always be. Then you should be able to equally space your `.contact` divs equally within without worrying about window size.

Comment: Tried changing to `width:1387px` with `.contact {margin: 0 100px; width: 140px;}` to test out spacing. `.contact` divs do not stayed centered with `#footer` bg image (or the rest of the page) when window is resized. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: `width:100%` was the issue. Changing to fixed pixel width just on `#contact-row` did not solve the problem because it's parent, `#footer` was also set to `width:100%`. Eliminating the extra div and changing to a fixed pixel width solved the problem. Thanks!